# How to draw a 2D/3D grid from BufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I have some points in a `BufferGeometry`. They arrange themselves into a regular 1D/2D/3D grid. I'm doing index mapping to higher dimensions, and moving the vertices dynamically so they end up in a proper spot relative to their neighbors (specifically, I'm visualizing a [self-organizing map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map)).

[image: 2]

I want to draw the connections between vertices, like the above picture. Doing that for 1D is straightforward enough because it's just a `new Line(myBufferGeometry)`, but how can the same be achieved for 2D and 3D? Do I have to create and update separate geometries for this, like make lots of 
`LineSegments`? How can this be done efficiently? Or maybe is there some "magic" I can do, like with the `index` property?

Comment: Use `THREE.LineSements()` with indexed `THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Oh, that's actually very helpful, I should've read the docs more carefully. Thanks, I'll check in in an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out thanks to prisoner849's comment - this isn't explicitly mentioned in the docs and kinda hidden away in examples, but this is exactly what the `index` property is for. When `LineSegments` is provided with a `GeometryBuffer` that has the property, the lines are based on pairs of indices rather than pairs of points in the `position` property.

Here's a complete solution for a n x n x n cube:

```
let nn = n * n;
let nnn = n * n * n;

function mapTo3D(index) {
    let x = index % n;
    let y = Math.floor(index / n) % n;
    let z = Math.floor(index / nn);
    return { x: x, y: y, z: z };
}

function mapFrom3D(x, y, z) {
    return x + y * n + z * nn;
}

// add nnn points to the position attribute of your myGeometryBuffer...

let indices3D = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nnn; i++) {
    var p = mapTo3D(i);
    if (p.x + 1 < n) {
        indices3D.push(i);
        indices3D.push(mapFrom3D(p.x + 1, p.y, p.z));
    }
    if (p.y + 1 < n) {
        indices3D.push(i);
        indices3D.push(mapFrom3D(p.x, p.y + 1, p.z));
    }
    if (p.z + 1 < n) {
        indices3D.push(i);
        indices3D.push(mapFrom3D(p.x, p.y, p.z + 1));
    }
}

myBufferGeometry.setIndex(indices3D);
let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(myBufferGeometry);
```

Comment: That's cool! Could you create a live code example and add it to a new topic of this theme on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) in `Resources` category?

Comment: Sure! I'll do it in a day or two.

Comment: _"and kinda hidden away in examples"_ I wouldn't say it like that :) https://threejs.org/examples/?q=indexed#webgl_buffergeometry_lines_indexed